# Using Application.cfc to route dns wildcards

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, dns, wildcard-subdomain, application.cfc

I'm using a godaddy coldfusion shared hosting account and I want to provide my users friendlier/direct urls.
I've added a wildcard to my domain so all subdomains point to the same root folder.

How do I use just the Application.cfc to route dns wildcards to their appropriate destinations?

`index.cfm` in the root folder will just list cities
Going to city.domain.com should bring up `domain.com/city/index.cfm` if it exists and `domain.com/index.cfm` if it doesn't.

I tried cflocation but I think it went into an infinite loop.

Comment: How are you determining cityname?  How are you determining where to forward the user?  Does this code exist in domain/cityname/index.cfm and application.cfc?  Code would be helpful.

Comment: Ben the user enters their city in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do a server side redirect, and hide it all away from the client.

So regular requests go to index.cfm (www.domain.com)

And then if there is a city (in onRequestStart()):

```
city = ListFirst(CGI.SERVER_NAME, ".");
if(!StructKeyExists(request, "forward") AND (city != "www" || city != "domain"))
{
   request.forward = 1;
   getPageContext().forward("/#city#/index.cfm");
   abort;
}
```

I put the request scope variable 'forward' in there to stop potential infinite loops, as the Application.cfc is called again.

You can see more details here:

http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=displayPost&ID=26

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#forward%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you're checking for the right thing in CGI.SERVER_NAME. Something like this should do the trick:

```
<cfif ListLen(CGI.SERVER_NAME, ".") NEQ 2 AND ListFirst(CGI.SERVER_NAME, ".") NEQ "www">
    <cflocation url="http://domain.com/#ListFirst(CGI.SERVER_NAME, ".")#/index.cfm" />
</cfif>
```

Comment: To even take it another step beyond Daniels solution I would do an if directoryExists('./#listFirst(CGI.SERVER_NAME,'.')#') to make sure the wildcard exists and if it doesn't, forward to an error page or a signup for or something like that.

Comment: Should this happen in the Application.cfc or in the root/index.cfm

Comment: I would probably place this in the onRequestStart, so that it would happen no matter where the user is in the domain. But this is completely up to you as far as how you want the redirect to work. If it should only ever happen when they hit /index.cfm, them put it in there. If you need this to happen anytime there is a cityname.domain.com URL, regardless of the file requested, then put it in onRequestStart in App.cfc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your existing code would work fine if placed at the top of root/index.cfm. You could supplement that with onMissingTemplate() in Application.cfc to handle 404 situations.